# Why is the martensite to austenite transition temperature in Shape Memory Alloys so much lower than in steel?

Tags: materials, metallurgy

When learning about Shape Memory Alloys (SMAs) I was told that the mechanism that allows for strain recovery in SMAs is the martensite to austenite transformation that occurs at low temperature around 90C. This transformation is named for the transformation that occurs in heat treatment in steels since the crystal structures of both are identical, although the transformation in steel occurs around 727C. My question is why is the transition temperature in NITINOL SMA so much lower than the transformation temperature of steels?

Comment: In steel, austenite only changes to martensite directly if cooling occurs rapidly enough (before sufficient diffusion of carbon to allow nucleation of ferrite). The transformation temperatures are usually significantly lower than 727C. Consider this [AISI 4340 IT diagram](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~stienstr/me%20328/2005Exam4_files/image002.jpg) which has the Martensite Start temperature closer to 290C. Not shown, but AISI 1095 is near 425C. 727C is the A1 temperature at which austenite and ferrite exchange stability.